# Unit Test Big Objects

Tags: apex, unit-test, controller, big-object, apexmock

I have an APEX controller that writes to a Big Object. How do I unit this? During an insert operation insert I get an error:

> Unsupported External Object Operations.

Answer (score 5):

I found these two references in the documentation for Big Objects:

- [Populate a Custom Big Object with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.bigobjects.meta/bigobjects/big_object_populate_apex.htm)

> Any Apex tests that use DML calls will fail and potentially insert bad data into the target big object. This data won’t be deletable. To test DML calls, use a mocking framework with the Apex stub API to contain calls to the target big object.

- [Build a Mocking Framework with the Stub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_stub_api.htm)

So it appears you will need to Mock the Big Objects for your test cases.

Comment: ApexMocks addresses second bullet; Force.com Enterprise Architecture patterns - Unit of Work layer is one pattern I've used to deal with these issues + apexMocks